# Creating more than one row in a CSV file/Chess database creation

Tags: python, csv, chess, python-chess

I am trying to create a database to train a basic machine learning algorithm off of. However, when I run the code, it only creates two rows, but I am trying to create multiple rows, of each individual position in the game, accompanied by a stockfish analysis at the end for the position. The code either seems to be making three moves, then writing the file or overwriting the file for each move. I cannot tell which one it is. To elaborate further, the example below is the output of the code I wrote, where number = 3:
[image: Output code gives me]

However, I am looking for something like this:

| 0 | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 | 6 | 7 | 8 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| P | P |  |  |  |  |  | p | p |
| P |  |  | P |  |  |  | p | p |
| P |  |  | P |  | p |  |  | p |

Here is my code:

```
import chess
import chess.engine
import random
import numpy
import csv
from stockfish import Stockfish

header = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28,29,30,31,32,33,34,35,36,37,38,39,40,41,42,43,44,45,46,47,48,49,50,51,52,53,54,55,56,57,58,59,60,61,62,63]
data = []



def create_file(number):
  board = chess.Board()
  moves = 0
  turns = 0
  black_v = 0
  white_v = 0
  while moves < number:
    if chess.Board.is_game_over(board) == True:
      chess.Board.reset()
    if turns > 200:
      chess.Board.reset()
    for position in header:
      data.append(board.piece_at(position))

    with open('/content/Positions Data/position.csv', 'w', encoding='UTF8', newline='') as f:
        writer = csv.writer(f)
        header.append('sf')
        data.append((stockfish(board, 10))/100)
        writer.writerow(header)
        writer.writerow(data)
        data.clear()
        header.pop()
        turns = turns + 1
        moves = moves + 1
        random_move = random.choice(list(board.legal_moves))
        board.push(random_move)
```

Comment: You open the file with the `'w'` mode. This overwrites all previously written data. So in your while loop only the last iteration will be stored in the file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As pointed out by Camaendir in the comment, you're opening your output file on every iteration of the move.  This will open the file "for creating" which overwrites any previous data.

Also, from looking at your code and what you're trying to do, I see there are two ways to accomplish what you want, and you're trying both at the same time and that's creating other issues.

Either open the CSV file for writing, and loop over your moves writing as you process the board/moves with `writer.writerow(stockfish(board, 10))/100)`:

1. open file for writing
2. create csv.Writer from file
3. write your header
4. loop over your moves

   1. process a move/board
   2. write move/board
5. close file

Or, process all the moves/board appending to `data`, then open your CSV file and write data `writer.writerows(data)`:

1. loop over your moves

   1. process a move/board
   2. append that to `data`
2. open file for writing
3. create csv.Writer from file
4. write your header
5. write all rows with `data`
6. close the file